# How to make an events base class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, object, properties, inheritance

I am trying to make an events class for a little canvas library that I am making!

This is what I have so far,

```
function Events() {

};

Events.prototype.addEvents = function() {

    this.mousemove = false;
    this.onMousemove = function() {

        if (this.mousemove) {
            this.mousemove();
        }
    };
    this.mousedown = false;
    this.onMousedown = function() {

        if (this.mousedown) {
            this.mousedown();
        }
    };
    this.mouseup = false;
    this.onMouseup = function() {

        if(this.mouseup) {
            this.mouseup();
        }
    };
    this.click = false;
    this.onClick = function() {

        if (this.click) {
            this.click();
        }
    };
    this.on = function(type, callback) {

    };

};
```

What I cannot do is now add this to other objects that I want to assign events on. For example another object would be a simple rectangle that has a draw method.

```
function Rect() {

    this.draw = function(context) {
         // code
    };
};

// How can I add Events prototype properties to Rect? I have tried...
// Rect.prototype = new Object.create(Events.prototype);
// Rect.prototype = Object.create(new Events.prototype);
```

I basically want the events prototype to give all of it's properties to another object that I want to have events on?

Thank you and I hope I made sense!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I'm not mistaken you want the prototype of `Rect()` to inherit the method `addEvent()` from the prototype of `Events()`.

You don't use `new` when using `Object.create`, so `new Object.create(Events.prototype)` is wrong. You could do this:

```
Rect.prototype = Object.create(Events.prototype);
```

But then, Object.create is not supported on Internet Explorer 8 and below, so maybe you'd rather use this function:

```
function inherit(children, parent) {
    var F = function() {};
    F.prototype = parent.prototype;
    children.prototype = new F();
    children.prototype.constructor = children;
};
```

There are several patterns for inheritance in JavaScript, this is just one of them. If you want to learn others you could take a look at Stoyan Stefanov's book [JavaScript Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do), but in any case, this one is going to do the job.

As you can see, it uses a temporary function F() as a link between the children and the parent. We could have done `children.prototype = parent.prototype`, but then if we at some point change something in children.prototype, we are going to be changing parent.prototype in fact - we probably don't want that.

We also don't want to do this: `Rect.prototype = new Events()`. That would also link Rect.prototype with Event's prototype, but if we did that, anything declared in Events with the keyword `this` will be going to be added to Rect - something that we probably don't want to happen. For example, if Events included `this.whatever = 'value'`, then `whatever` would be added to `Rect.prototype`.

So you simply would call the described inherit function and pass the two functions as the arguments, in this way:

```
inherit(Rect, Events);
```

And Rect.prototype, then, is going to inherit the methods of Event's prototype.

Comment: Edited to clarify a little bit more the explanation. I typed it too fast the first time and explained incorrectly the benefits of having a temporary constructor F().

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, this might help you.

```
$.fn.addEvents = function() {

    this.mousemove = false;
    this.onMousemove = function() {

        if (this.mousemove) {
            this.mousemove();
        }
    };
    this.mousedown = false;
    this.onMousedown = function() {

        if (this.mousedown) {
            this.mousedown();
        }
    };
    this.mouseup = false;
    this.onMouseup = function() {

        if(this.mouseup) {
            this.mouseup();
        }
    };
    this.click = false;
    this.onClick = function() {

        if (this.click) {
            this.click();
        }
    };
    this.on = function(type, callback) {

    };

};
```

Now, call the above function as follows:

```
$(selector).addEvents();
```

I hope this will help you.
Thank you.